# Problem with Battleship program that adds more ships than the maximum amount of ships allowed

Tags: java

My assignment requires me to create several different Java classes in order to simulate a game of Battleship. The program is currently able to create the grid, the ships, assign the locations of the ships, and create a player. However when I run the program, the grading system tells me that the program should "Ignore adding more ships if there are already 5 ships". I've tried to make several changes to my code but nothing has worked.

How can I make my program stop adding ships if there are 5 ships that are already created?

Here is the code for Player.java (the class that will add the ships to the grid):

```
public class Player
{
    private static final int[] SHIP_LENGTHS = {2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
    private static final int NUM_OF_SHIPS = 5;
    private Ship[] ships;
    private Grid a = new Grid();
    private Grid b = new Grid(); 


    public Player() 
    {
        ships = new Ship[NUM_OF_SHIPS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SHIPS; i++) 
        {
            ships[i] = new Ship(SHIP_LENGTHS[i]);
        }
    }

    public void printMyShips()
    {
        a.printShips();
    }


    public void printOpponentGuesses()
    {
        b.printStatus();
    }


    public void printMyGuesses()
    {
        a.printStatus();
    }

    public void chooseShipLocation(Ship s, int row, int col, int direction)
    {
        s.setLocation(row, col);
        s.setDirection(direction);
        a.addShip(s);
    }


    public void recordOpponentGuess(int row, int col)
    {
        if (a.hasShip(row, col)) 
        {
            b.markHit(row, col);
        }
        else 
        {
            b.markMiss(row, col);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for Grid.java (the class which is used to create a grid and add ships to it):

```
public class Grid {

    private Location[][] grid;
    public static final int NUM_ROWS = 10;
    public static final int NUM_COLS = 10;

    public Grid() 
    {
        grid = new Location[NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];
        for (int y = 0; y < NUM_ROWS; y++) 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < NUM_COLS; x++) 
            {
                grid[x][y] = new Location();
            }
        }
    }


    public void markHit(int row, int col) 
    {
        grid[col][row].markHit();
    }


    public void markMiss(int row, int col) 
    {
        grid[col][row].markMiss();
    }


    public void setStatus(int row, int col, int status) 
    {
        grid[col][row].setStatus(status);
    }


    public int getStatus(int row, int col) 
    {
        return grid[col][row].getStatus();
    }


    public boolean alreadyGuessed(int row, int col) 
    {
        return !grid[col][row].isUnguessed();
    }


    public void setShip(int row, int col, boolean val) 
    {
        grid[col][row].setShip(val);
    }


    public boolean hasShip(int row, int col) 
    {
        return grid[col][row].hasShip();
    }



    public Location get(int row, int col) 
    {
        return grid[col][row];
    }


    public int numRows() 
    {
        return NUM_ROWS;
    }


    public int numCols() 
    {
        return NUM_COLS;
    }

    public void printStatus() 
    {
        String[] alpha = 
        {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J",
            "K",
            "L",
            "M",
            "N"
        };
        System.out.print("");
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
            if (i != 9) 
            {
                System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.print(i + 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

        for (int y = 0; y < NUM_ROWS; y++) 
        {
            System.out.print(alpha[y] + " ");
            for (int x = 0; x < NUM_COLS; x++) 
            {
                if (grid[x][y].checkHit()) 
                {
                    System.out.print("X ");
                } else if (grid[x][y].checkMiss()) 
                {
                    System.out.print("O ");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.print("- ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public void printShips() 
    {
        String[] alpha = 
        {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J",
            "K",
            "L",
            "M",
            "N"
        };
        System.out.print("");
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) 
        {
            if (i != 9) 
            {
                System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.print(i + 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

        for (int y = 0; y < NUM_ROWS; y++) 
        {
            System.out.print(alpha[y] + " ");
            for (int x = 0; x < NUM_COLS; x++) 
            {
                if (grid[x][y].hasShip()) 
                {
                    System.out.print("X ");
                } 
                else System.out.print("- ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public void addShip(Ship s) 
    {
        int length = s.getLength();
        int dir = s.getDirection();
        int row = s.getRow();
        int col = s.getCol();

        if (dir == 1) 
        {
            for (int y = row; y < (s.getLength() + row); y++) 
            {
                setShip(y, col, true);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            for (int x = col; x < (s.getLength() + col); x++) 
            {
                setShip(row, x, true);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For player.java, use this

```js
public class Player
{
    private static final int[] SHIP_LENGTHS = {2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
    private static final int NUM_OF_SHIPS = 5;
    private Ship[] ships;
    private Grid myGrid = new Grid();
    private Grid enemyGrid = new Grid(); 
    private int shipCount = 0;

    
    public Player(){
        ships = new Ship[NUM_OF_SHIPS];
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SHIPS; i++){
            ships[i] = new Ship(SHIP_LENGTHS[i]);
        }
    }
    
    public void printMyShips(){
        myGrid.printShips();
    }
    
    public void printOpponentGuesses(){
        enemyGrid.printStatus();
    }
    
    public void printMyGuesses()
    {
        myGrid.printStatus();
    }
    
    public void chooseShipLocation(Ship ship, int row, int col, int direction){
        if(shipCount < 5){
            ship.setLocation(row, col);
            ship.setDirection(direction);
            myGrid.addShip(ship);
            shipCount++;
        }
    }
    
    public void recordOpponentGuess(int row, int col){
        if(myGrid.hasShip(row, col)){
            enemyGrid.markHit(row, col);
        }
        else{
            enemyGrid.markMiss(row, col);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work, as you can add the same ship multiple times. for example add ship of length 5 twice